# Genitiv "alleinstehend"?

Tags: genitive

Possessivpronomen können im Deutschen nicht attributiv verwendet werden, z. B.

> *Wessen Stift ist das? – Das ist **meiner**.*

Würde dies auch mit Genitiv gehen? Kann man den Genitiv ohne Folgenomen benutzen?
(etwa so?)

> *Wessen Stift ist das? - ¿? Das ist **Serenas***.

Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das geht schon, aber das ist eine sogenannte "Ellipse" - eine Konstruktion, die sich einer Auslassung bedient. Die Antwort auf die Frage "Wessen Stift ist das?" wäre genaugenommen "Das ist Serenas Stift.". Weil das "Stift" aber offensichtlich ist, wird es weggelassen.

Diese Methode (die vorgenannte "Ellipse") gibt es auch in anderen Formulierungen:

- A: "Ich habe fünf Stücke. Und du?"
- B: "Ich habe sieben."

Hier wird "Und du hast wieviele?" um den offensichtlichen Teil verkürzt und auch die Antwort läßt das "Stück" weg.

In all diesen Fällen ist das (weggelassene) Objekt im Akkusativ, (wen? die Stücke!; wen? den Stift!), das Genitivobjekt bestimmt nur das Objekt näher: wen? Serenas Stift!